# marking origin of logs in logstash

Tags: docker, logstash, docker-compose, elastic-stack

I send logs from my Docker containers to Logstash via netcat to tcp port.
Their format is mostly similar, so pattern-matching is not very well suitable.

Is there a way to send those logs with a tag, being a name of docker container they originate from?

Comment: With a shipper like filebeat, you can add tags to your logs, and it will survive when logstash is down.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use something like [tiller](https://github.com/markround/tiller) to write out your Logstash configuration dynamically, and [add a tag](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-tags) to the outbound log stream?

You could then use an ENTRYPOINT statement to kick off the tiller script, write out the config, and start your Logstash forwarder.